# Batch function: Incrementing not working

Tags: batch-file

Again a stupid question, but.. why the heck does this batch function produce a file full of 0's and not 1, 2, 3, 4... and so on?
Is there some sorcery required?... I've read through examples without results.

```
:fixHtml

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a count=0

>"%~2" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~1") do  (
    if %count%==1 (echo "ABCD") else (echo %count%)
    set /a count=count+1
  )
)

endlocal
goto:eof
```

The function is modified for testing purposes. Later it should just modify the lines of the original file (argument %1) depending on the position of the counter and produce file two (%2).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got delayed expansion enabled, but you aren't using it.

Change `if %count%==1 (echo "ABCD") else (echo %count%)`

to `if !count!==1 (echo "ABCD") else (echo !count!)`

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much! Think I must have been blind...
One question though, in case you can help. Since I'm modifying the file only partially, I use the line as following:
 if !count!==1 (echo "ABCD") else (echo. %%A )
But this has the result that the string ' <!-- ' from the original file is being changed to: ' <-- '. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I believe you can get around it with `echo "%%A"`